# Can I individually style items in the backend widget list?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, widgets, wp-admin

**UPDATE** Refrased the question

On the backend widget page `widgets.php`, there is a list of available widgets. Items in this list have the same classes and a [dynamically generated ID](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_widgets/), which changes if a new widget is inserted (alphabetically) into the list. So, there is no reliable way to direct css at individual items in the list.

Is there another way to style individual items in the widget list?

**Old, more narrow question**

I have a theme which includes a [font icon](http://fontawesome.io/) in its full name. It's defined globally like this:

```
$theme_data      = wp_get_theme(); // Retrieves the theme data from style.css
$theme_name      = $theme_data['Name'];
$theme_icon      = '<i class="fa fa-wrench" style="font-family:FontAwesome;"></i>';
$theme_full_name = $theme_icon . ' ' . $theme_name;
```

I can use `$theme_full_name` in menus, page titles and so on. There's one exception, however. The theme includes two widgets, which also have `$theme_full_name` in their name (the second parameter [in the constructor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API)). On the `widgets.php` page in the admin only the theme name appears. Apparently the icon is stripped away (as is, presumably, all html that might be in the widget name).

Is there a way to retain the font icon in the widget name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as @MarkKaplun [mentioned](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/243718/can-i-individually-style-items-in-the-backend-widget-list/244667#comment363657_243719) in a comment, it's possible with CSS. Also with Javascript.

### CSS Approach

Let's look at the *Calendar* widget, as an example.

The *id* for the widget, in the *available widgets* list, is of the form:

```
widget-{integer}_calendar-__i__
```

and in the sidebar it's:

```
widget-{integer}_calendar-{integer}
```

If we want to display the [calendar dashicon](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#calendar) before the widget title, then we can e.g. enqueue a custom stylesheet for the `widgets.php` file, with something like:

```
div[id*="_calendar-"].widget .widget-title h3:before{ 
    content: "\f145"; font-family: dashicons; margin-right: 0.5rem; 
}
```

Here we use `*=` to find a substring match within the id selector.

It will display like this:

[image: calendar]

If needed we could restrict this further to the *right* or *left* parts:

```
#widgets-right
#widgets-left
```

or the available widgets:

```
#available-widgets
```

The `widgets.php` page will also have `body.widgets-php` if needed for general stylesheets.

Comment: Smart! I hadn't thought of css-selectors in this way. Downside of the css approach is that it only works if your font icon is the first or last character in your name, not if it is halfway as in "Hello [cat icon] Kitty". But that could probably be done with jquery.

Comment: Javascript would be better to split the title text with an icon, as you say. ps: Here I assumed a *ltr* language, so we might also want to adjust to *rtl* with `body.rtl`. Now I wonder if *widget icons* should be a core feature ;-) @cjbj

Answer (score -1):

Indeed, all html is stripped from the widget name in the backend by this line (WP 4.6) in the [`wp_widget_control`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_widget_control/) function:

```
$widget_title = esc_html( strip_tags( $sidebar_args['widget_name'] ) );
```

Now, there is no apparent way to intercept `strip_tags`, because it is a php function, but [`esc_html`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/) is a WP function, that has a filter. So, we cannot prevent the icon/html being stripped, but we can add it back again using the filter. Like this:

```
add_filter ('esc_html','wpse243718_add_icon_to_widget_name');

function wpse243718_add_icon_to_widget_name ($safe_text) {
    global $theme_icon;
    global $theme_name;
    global $pagenow;
    if ( ($pagenow == 'widgets.php') && (substr($safe_text, 0, strlen($theme_name)) == $theme_name) )
        return $theme_icon  . ' ' . $safe_text;
    else
        return $safe_text;
    }
```

This code assumes the widget name starts with `$theme_name`, but you could use other ways of detection as well, of course, or stuff your title with all kinds of html.

Comment: sorry, but IMHO it is an horrible idea to mess with that filter, double that from doing it from a plugin or theme just to make an icon be seen. Probably can be done in CSS without this kind of risk

Comment: I see your point, but if it could be done with css, I'd have chosen that path. the problem is there are no stable id's or classes to work with.

Comment: I am negatively surprised there is a filter at all. Anyway since your code uses globals and it will be hard not to use them, any hacker can add an innocent looking code which sets the globals and bypass the escaping to add his own evil JS

Comment: Yup. Any hacker who gets as far as being able to manipulate globals can get his fingers on this filter anyway. (I was also quite surprised to find it, be assured that I fiddled with it and was up for more surprises where I could dump html and js in my admin interface).

Comment: The globals are not necessary, by the way. I could also use functions to retrieve icon and name from the options table. But that doesn't change the weakness.

Comment: well, the evilness is the existance of the filter.... I will be surprised if the TRT checks for its usage :(